# Can I optimize the ReadString method in an mfc program?

Tags: mfc

I wrote an MFC program that opens a large text file to search through it. The program currently searches through the file line by line, all ~700,000 of them. It picks out specific lines containing the user's desired hexadecimal ID tag and converts a separate portion of that line into binary to be written to a new text file. This program is taking about 15 seconds or so to complete this task, which seems like much too long. I have done some diagnostics and it looks like there is an issue with the ReadString() method I am using to read in each line. Is there any way I can optimize this? The text file displays the different IDs in no particular order so I wasn't able to think of some algorithm to search through this file more easily.

Comment: Is this the Debug or Release build of your app?  Also, are you using any type of UI element to display the contents of the file, appending the text line by line?  If so, eliminate that.  You may also tweak your app to eliminate any "parsing" and just time how long it takes to perform ReadString for all 700,000 lines to see if that is actually the bottle-neck (it could be the parsing of the lines, e.g. a non-optimal regular expression grammar or ???).

Comment: It is in both the debug and release build which performs this way. My program does use parsing to pick out certain parts in each line, so that could also be part of the issue. How would I go about timing the ReadString method in the program? I looked around for something but couldn't find anything yet

Comment: you stated that it takes 15 seconds to do all the work.  Just comment out the parsing part you do for each line, then re-run the program on the same data file.  If it does all the identical work, except for the parsing, and that takes 5 seconds, you know the parsing part takes 10 seconds and everything else takes 5 (i.e. the primary bottle neck is NOT the ReadString).

Comment: Okay I've figured it out. I have the ReadString in a while statement like this -->  while(file.ReadString(line) != FALSE){parsing code here} and when i commented literally everything inside the while statement so that the program simply read in each line, it still took about 15 seconds. And I added some code to record times and that further proved this is what is causing it. I guess I'll have to accept it since I don't know of any way to make this function any faster..

Comment: From your description, there are 2 costly operations that can be optimized: `1` Accessing the disk is slow. Depending on the `CStdioFile` implementation, this could be a potential bottleneck. Either read the whole file in one go, or - better - use a file mapping object. `2` The `ReadString` operation allocates heap memory. Lots of temporary string objects contribute to heap fragmentation (heap allocations aren't cheap either). A better approach is to operate on the mapped memory directly. (An MFC-compatible implementation can be found at [CMemMapFile](http://www.naughter.com/memmap.html)).

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not be faster, but the obvious alternative would be to read the whole file (or large chunks of it) with CFile::Read and then search the buffer for a hex ID field with memchr().